# Unable to postback asp:GridView with large data set

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview

**BACKGROUND**

A page in our application contains an `asp:GridView` control in an `UpdatePanel` which, itself, is contained in an `UpdatePanel`.

The outer `UpdatePanel` has `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and `ChildrenAsTriggers="false"`.

The `UpdatePanel` that contains the `GridView` has `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"`.

Originally, the `GridView` would load the data for up to 3,000 facility locations, depending on which company was selected from an Infragistics `WebDataTree`. The names of the facilities were also loaded into the `WebDataTree` as subnodes of the currently selected node.

**THE ISSUE**

When the number of facilities is quite large, attempting to sort or page through the grid, or to select another node in the tree view produces this exception:

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The maximum number of items has already been deserialized into a single dictionary by the JavaScriptSerializer. To change the maximum allowed JSON dictionary entry count from its current value of 10000, change the "aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" setting. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238386 for more information.

**THE QUESTION**

Aside from the standard solution (shown in the error message above), which does not work, how do I resolve this issue?

**WHAT WE'VE TRIED**

1. I attempted to resolve it by steadily increasing the value of `asp:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers` until it was capped out at 2,147,483,647. Just to be doubly sure, I also increased the value of `maxJsonLength` to the same value. Neither has had any effect.
2. We've refined the UI so that only one tree node has child nodes, and, if the number of facilities is greater than 50, we only load data into the grid for companies with the same first letter, significantly reducing the size of the data loaded into the grid
3. We turned off ViewState for everything imaginable. Unfortunately, the tree view control is inoperable without it.

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Are you using viewstate or session here? If you use viewstate, then that travels to the client side - any postback going to post-back the gride display AND ALSO the viewstate - it going to be quite slow. However, you could consider using server side state in place of view state if you are persisting the dataset that way. Also, consider adding some kind of data paging routines - so you only display one page at a time (don't use the built in data pager - it works on the whole data set). So, in theory, you would/should ONLY be persisting one page of data here. Try session in place of viewstate

Comment: @JobesK I can't show the markup and server-side code for confidentiality reasons. Besides, it would be a lot of code. I can tell you that the GridView is populated server-side using a DataTable that is populated from a SQL Server stored procedure that loads 3,055 rows. The WebDataTree contains 26 root nodes, a couple thousand child nodes, and one of the child nodes contains the 3,055 nodes that also appear in the GridView.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal We are using ViewState. I did try to reduce its usage as much as possible, but the response is still far too large to be processed. I will propose a refactor to use session state and manual paging, but it represents a substantial (and potentially prohibitively expensive) level of effort (not my call).

Comment: Using session in place of viewstate should not require much changes for that one page. Ultimately, one should page that data anyway (not a gridview data pager control, but use sql server data paging). I don't think anything more then 100-300 rows of data should ever be pulled anyway, and persisting that much data in viewstate? Any page post-back going to send that whole boatload of data BACK up to the server on any button click. Using session would 100% eliminate the heavy browser payload anyway. If you are persisting a dataset, then use session for that. Treeview probably can't be changed.

Comment: In other words, that treeview? Sure, let it keep its viewstate. But, if any other data such as a datatable/dataset or anything else? Use session for those. You can probably even let the gv keep its viewstate, but any varables for code behind, such as noted datatable/dataset? Move those to session(). Thus little code changes would/should be  required here.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I agree, and this will be the change I propose to the team. What's odd is that the postback that occurs within the update panel doesn't appear to be sending *only* the contents of the UpdatePanel; instead, it appears to be sending the contents of the entire page. I've reduced the contents of the grid down to 20 rows of data in one test, and it still produces the error above. The UpdatePanel contains *only* the GridView.

Comment: contents of a update panel only go back on post-back, but viewstate I believe will also/always be posted back. I don't think that the viewstate is split out and spit apart in this process. So, while the controls outside of the viewstate can't be modified, and 
 are not sent back to server, the viewstate will be same in size and posted back.